# Is it possible to use SignalR on a Node.js backend?

Tags: node.js, asp.net, react-native, websocket, signalr

I'm aware that the library [@microsoft/signalr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr) can be used on the client-side to connect with a SignalR hub, but is it possible to integrate SignalR in a node server? We're trying to implement a chat system using SignalR with React Native as the client but we can't figure out how to integrate it into Node or is it just meant to be used with the ASP.NET server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SignalR server must be hosted in a .NET application, because it is implemented as a .NET Class Library. SignalR clients are available for many languages/platforms, including JavaScript and Node.

If you want to do real time communications or two way communication using Node as the server, you'll need to look into other options.